# Python: Convert list of sets to dictionary with indexes

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, set

I'm trying to convert the following list:

```
listOfSets = [{"dog", "cat", "bird"}, {"blue", "yellow", "white"}]
```

To a dictionary like:

```
dictt =  {"dog" : 0, "cat" : 0, "bird" : 0, "blue" : 1,  "yellow" : 1, "white" : 1}}
```

I've tried suggestions from other posts here with no success,
for example, I tried to use enumerate and get the following error:

```
Type error Unhashable type:set
```

looking of course for the clearest and elegant way to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably iterating over the set, instead of the elements of the set, do this:

```
listOfSets = [{"dog", "cat", "bird"}, {"blue", "yellow", "white"}]

result = {si : i for i, s in enumerate(listOfSets) for si in s}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'bird': 0, 'cat': 0, 'dog': 0, 'blue': 1, 'white': 1, 'yellow': 1}
```

The above [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) is equivalent to the following:

```
listOfSets = [{"dog", "cat", "bird"}, {"blue", "yellow", "white"}]

result = {}
for i, s in enumerate(listOfSets):
    for si in s:
        result[si] = i

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this

```
listOfSets = [{"dog", "cat", "bird"}, {"blue", "yellow", "white"}]

>>> dict(list((s,i) for i, j in enumerate(listOfSets) for s in j))
{'cat': 0, 'bird': 0, 'dog': 0, 'white': 1, 'yellow': 1, 'blue': 1}
```